# How does firefox sync password recovery work?

Tags: security, firefox, encryption, passwords

According to Mozilla's article, [Firefox Sync's new security model](http://blog.mozilla.org/services/2014/04/30/firefox-syncs-new-security-model/), **Firefox servers are not able to decrypt your sync data** without your password.

So I figure that the browser generates a key from your password, encrypts the data and sends it over the wire without the key.
But if I forget my password, I can still recover it, by having firefox **send a password reset** email. According to [this knowledgebase article](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ive-lost-my-firefox-sync-account-information), you can't recover your sync password without your email.

1. How does password reset work?
2. How is Firefox able to **decrypt** your data on their servers without your old key and send it back to your browser for syncing?
3. Does it stores the old key somewhere or is there some weird crypto magic going on?

Comment: I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place for this question. It might better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've just posted it there as well: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73903/how-does-firefox-sync-password-recovery-work